# Magento Custom Header

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, header

I create custom header in cart page like this

```
<checkout_cart_index> 
    <reference name="root"> 
        <block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/html/cartheader.phtml</template></action> 
        </block>          
    </reference>

    <reference name="footer">
        <block type="cms/block" name="Shopping Cart" before="footer_links">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>shoppingcart</block_id></action>
        </block>        
    </reference>

</checkout_cart_index>
```

then i see my log files it shows below error what is problem on it's

> 2016-05-06T05:35:51+00:00 ERR (3): 
>       exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Page_Block_Header' in /var/www/html/domain/app/Mage.php:595
>       Stack trace:
>       #0 /var/www/html/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495):
>   Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
>       #1 /var/www/html/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('page/header', Array)
>       #2 /var/www/html/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('page/header', 'header')
>       #3 /var/www/html/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('page/header', 'header')
>       #4 /var/www/html/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element),
>   Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
>       #5 /var/www/html/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
>       #6 /var/www/html/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
>       #7 /var/www/html/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
>       #8 /var/www/html/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(212):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout()
>       #9 /var/www/html/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418):
>   Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->indexAction()
>       #10 /var/www/html/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
>       #11 /var/www/html/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
>       #12 /var/www/html/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
>       #13 /var/www/html/domain/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>       #14 /var/www/html/domain/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
>       #15 {main}

Answer (score 1):

Block type is `page/html_header` not `page/header`

Change below code

```
       <reference name="header"> 
            <block type="page/header" name="header">
                <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/html/cartheader.phtml</template></action> 
            </block>
            <remove name="navigation-link"/>
            <remove name="cms_footer_links"/>            
        </reference>
```

to:

```
   <reference name="header">            
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/html/cartheader.phtml</template></action>            
        <remove name="navigation-link"/>
        <remove name="cms_footer_links"/>            
    </reference>
```

Comment: Still same error

Comment: Update answer please check it will surely work

Comment: No Luck Same Error

Comment: It is working for me may be there is other issue.Clear cache and check it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<reference name="header">
    <block type="page/header" name="header">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/html/cartheader.phtml</template></action> 
    </block> 
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this with `root` reference

```
<checkout_cart_index> 
              <reference name="root">
  <block type="core/template" name="header" as="header" template="page/html/cartheader.phtml"/>
</reference>

        <reference name="footer">
            <block type="cms/block" name="Shopping Cart" before="footer_links">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>shoppingcart</block_id></action>
            </block>        
        </reference>

    </checkout_cart_index>
```

other solution is

copy **app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Header.php**

to **app/code/local/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Header.php**

change template in construct

```
public function _construct()
    {
      $currentUrl = Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current' => true));
  if (strpos($currentUrl,'checkout/cart') == true) {
        $this->setTemplate('page/html/cartheader.phtml');
  } else { $this->setTemplate('page/html/header.phtml'); }
    }
```

Comment: Still same i have a doubt it relatedt to header error or what

Comment: did you check error log and remove the cache folder

Comment: Yes Still same only \

Comment: update the code try that..

Comment: No luck same error

Comment: added the new code make sure your phtml name is correct.

Comment: Check my updated question

Comment: did you try new added code? check that feedback

Comment: try this it is working `<reference name="root">
  <block type="core/template" name="header" as="header" template="page/html/cartheader.phtml"/>
</reference>`

Comment: add the new solution kindly check and feedback

Comment: After add this header not display in cart page

Comment: actually they are setting the template in block file added from block solution too

Comment: remove the xml code use only block code the check..

Comment: Still same i will check once and let you know

Comment: Hi can you please check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123976/magento-split-order-does-not-work-in-custom-payment-method